# Trying to use multiple IF statement with search function in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use the`IF`statement with the`SEARCH`and`LEFT`functions in Excel to search for a string and then display the string.

The first portion of the`IF`statement is working but it's not working for second. Please let me know what is wrong with my code. The statements work fine separately but when I use the code as nested`IF`statement it doesn't work.

```
=IF(SEARCH("COST", A4, 1), LEFT(A4, (SEARCH("COST", A4, 1) -1)), IF(SEARCH("VSE", A4, 1), LEFT(A4, (SEARCH( "VSE", A4, 1) -1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2007 and up you can try this:

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(LEFT(A4,SEARCH("COST",A4)-1),LEFT(A4,SEARCH("VSE",A4)-1)),"")`

Problem is, if **COST** is not found, it errors out so it will not proceed with finding **VSE**. HTH.